# Convert incoming emails to "txt/plain" script not working in hMailServer

Tags: vba, email, vbscript, outlook

I need to convert all my incoming email to "Plain Text" format.

I tested following code in Outlook 2010 and it worked without any issue. All HTML format emails have been converted to text/plain successfully. However, it did not work in the hMailServer script.

Only the error ""ERROR" 14960   "2015-03-20 19:13:23.673"   "Script Error: Source: Microsoft VBScript " could be found in the ERROR_hmailserver.log

Is there anyone can help check what the reason cause this error and how to solve it? Thank you so much!

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim arrEID As Variant, varEID As Variant, olkItm As Object
    arrEID = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For Each varEID In arrEID
        Set olkItm = Session.GetItemFromID(varEID)
        If olkItm.Class = olMail Then

                olkItm.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
                olkItm.Save

        End If
    Next
    Set olkItm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event (as any other properties) of the Application class comes from the Outlook object model and doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any script can be used for this purpose?

Comment: I suppose you need to ask hMailServer experts instead.